# Defining multiple interface definitions in /etc/network/interfaces and /etc/network/interfaces.d

Tags: networking

Is it possible to have an interface definition for say `eth0` in `/etc/network/interfaces.d/eth0.cfg` and a section in `/etc/network/interfaces`?

If this is possible, is there a *precedence* for one over the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My hint comes from the stack trace in https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ifupdown/+bug/1235169. See #1 comment. You can see below `/etc/network/interfaces` then `/etc/network/interfaces.d`.

```
read_interfaces_defn(..., '/etc/network/interfaces'
Reading directory /etc/network/interfaces.d
Parsing file eth0
read_interfaces_defn(..., 'eth0') failed in directory '/root'
Parsing file eth1
read_interfaces_defn(..., 'eth1') failed in directory '/root'
Parsing file eth2
read_interfaces_defn(..., 'eth2') failed in directory '/root'
Parsing file eth3
read_interfaces_defn(..., 'eth3') failed in directory '/root'
Parsing file eth4
read_interfaces_defn(..., 'eth4') failed in directory '/root'
Parsing file lo
read_interfaces_defn(..., 'lo') failed in directory '/root'
run-parts --verbose /etc/network/if-pre-up.d
run-parts --verbose /etc/network/if-up.d
run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-up.d/000resolvconf
run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-up.d/ntpdate
run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-up.d/postfix
run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-up.d/upstart
```

Also from the stack trace here https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/1092 you can see that it will complain for duplicates.

```
/etc/network/interfaces:17: duplicate interface
ifup: couldn't read interfaces file "/etc/network/interfaces"
```

Comment: These seem to be quite old, Saucy timeframe, hope things havent changed much in 14.04.